# How can I distinguish every second element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Please help me to solve this css style issue.

I have a multiple div tags, with class of 'a' or 'b'.
And I want to differentiate css style for every 2nd div tag with class 'a', without care of 'b'.

```css
.a:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
</div>
```

But it does not work, and my CSS always works without care of .a or .b.
This is execution result.
[image: screen capture]

Comment: `:nth-of-type(2n)` is applied to the element, not the class. So the style will be applied to every other element, if that element also has the `a` class.

Comment: Then what is the right solution for this issue? class 'a' and 'b' are div tags... so I have to cascade elements by class only.

Comment: If you are outputting the HTML from some kind of back end system, I'd use that to add a class to the second element with class "a". Otherwise, JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

this is not how `nth-child` works, but you can use the `~`selector to filter the second occurance of a class and then reset CSS for any other following.

If the idea was to select **one out of two apparance each time** of a class, alike `:nth-of-class(2n)` *(which is is not avalaible)*, **then Javascript will be required**.

Example, taking the second `.a` or `.b` class within the flow of a single parent, that another class or element stands in between or not .

```css
div .a,
div .b,
.a~.a~.a,
.b~.b~.b {
  background: #5f9ea0
}

.a~.a{
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.b~.b {
  background-color: orange;/* to avoid confusion ... */
}


/* demo purpose */

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5em, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 4em;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
</div>
```

Your selector : `.a:nth-of-type(2n)` is not filtering on `of-type`, since it only gets a class for selector , it will match any 2n tags standing in the flow and will apply the CSS rules if it also has a class `.a`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what the OP desires, which is to make every second element with "class a" have a chocolate background, at least in Edge Version 87.0.637.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit), where it shows the second "class a" and the second "class b" having a chocolate background...

Comment: @HereticMonkey nth-child cannot do it, unless you use js, the only CSS way  is to use the ~ selector twice, once to select the next in the flow and another to select again the next from the third occurance to reset styles. **example show for** the `.a` class **and also** the `.b` class , to make it clear it works ;)

Comment: Save your time. You **can't** count elements by calss names! that's a standard.

Comment: @Becky , **that's exactly the point of that answer.**  You can forget about nth- selector for this kind of behavior. but there is other ways to do it.

Comment: I know it can't do it; I was commenting that `~` can't do it either. The solution you're showing is not working, as it's not setting the background of the fourth element with class "a".

Comment: Since the OP is already having a way of passing `.a` or `.b`, there should be a much simpler way of adding an additinal class for evey 2nd `.a`. Anyways hope you get the correct formula to filter this :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey okay, then i misinterpreted : *I want to differentiate css style for every 2nd div tag with class 'a'* (i think i was not the only one. the op will clarify ;)

Comment: @Becky i think we read the question differently ;)

Comment: oh! you're correct... but I wouldn't try this though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct argument for the nth-child pseudo class.

The argument should be in the form of an + b to match every ath child starting from b.

Both a and b are optional integers and both can be zero or negative.

If a is zero then there is no "every ath child" clause.
If a is negative then matching is done backwards starting from b.
If b is zero or negative then it is possible to write equivalent expression using positive b e.g. 4n+0 is same as 4n+4. Likewise 4n-1 is same as 4n+3.

Also you can See : http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It says there is an answer to the question (maybe), and points to a site which may or may not answer the question, but the answer is not contained in the post...

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misperception
Unfortunately, the `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` css selectors do not look at `"class"` or anything else for counting.

They only look at either

- (1) all elements, or
- (2) all elements of a certain "type" (not class, not an attribute, nothing but the type of element--div or li etc.).

Therefore, if you don't know the exact Html structure, you cannot skip it with pure CSS.
And if you need to do that, you can do it using Javascript.

I have attached the implementations based on Javascript.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

for (let index = 1; index < elements.length; index += 2) {
  elements[index].classList += " different";
}
```

```css
.different {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="a">class a</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
  <div class="b">class b</div>
</div>
```